# Greek characters not being stored properly in c++ character array

Tags: c++, encoding, internationalization

In the debugger the characters are stored as the euro signs when the user inputs one of the characters here. Note these are all Greek characters not latin ones. The wcout outputs properly though.

The purpose of the code below is to add 1 into the leksarithm variable when the user types the Greek capital letter Α into the console.

```
    std::locale::global(std::locale("el_GR.utf8"));
    

    int i = 0;
    int leksarithm = 0;

    wchar_t leksi[100];

    std::wcout << L"Γράψε λέξη σε κεφαλαία Ελληνικά γράμματα να σου βγάλω τον λεξάριθμό της\n";
    wcin >> leksi;
    while (leksi[i] != '\0') {
        switch (leksi[i]) {
            case 'Α': leksarithm = leksarithm + 1; break;
            
           
        }
        i++;
}
```

I typed Α in the console when prompted but the answer was 0 instead of the expected 1. If I change the code to the Latin A and type it on the prompt as well it works fine.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Those are wide characters, so add an `L` before each of those character constants. e.g., `case L'Α':`. Not sure that's all you'll need, but at least it's a starting point to where it'll compile cleanly.

Comment: Is it better now? My first ever question on this website.

Comment: It's good practice to reduce your problem to a small subset of the initial problem. That way you can focus on the important stuff, but also eliminate possible unknown side effects causing the problem. From your question I still don't understand what your program is supposed to do. A minimal _compiling_ program would be a good start. You are also not incrementing `i`.

Comment: What about now?

Answer (score 2):

In your case: labels, `case 'A'` for instance, `'A'` is an ordinary `char`. Since you are working with wide strings, what you want is a wide character literal `L'A'` instead (see [Character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal)).

Comment: It now stores itself as the end '\0' character.